# Best Practices Java Trust Store

Tags: java, ssl

I have a client/server application that sends data over SSLSockets, so I generated a cert and loaded it with a trust store and keystore. The client is going to be public, so in order to work I need the client to have the javaTrustStore.jts file with it. Is it ok to bundle it in the resources directory? Or should I have the client generate a new key every time and add it to the server's keystore?

Comment: For a (static) private key it is never ok to be in customers hands / app because it's not longer private if you expose it in any such untrusted environment. Simple Web SSL only needs the client to have the servers public certificate. With client authentication you have to make sure that this certificate' private key isn't public, by selling it to customers, hiding it in a hardware crypto module on a device, generate them for each customer individually, .. and when the client generates it, don't transfer the key, look up CSR

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways that you can approach this.

The first is to have a certificate just on the server, and no certificate on the client.

The is the usual way that websites work - when the SSL connection is negotiated, the server sends it's certificate to the client, and the client verifies that the server cert is signed by a [Certificate Authority](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certificate_authority) that the client trusts. Most (all?) web browsers are pre-loaded with a number of certificate authoritys' "master certificates",

So, a Java application operating in this mode would need the "master CA certificate", and any "intermediate" signing certificates in it's trust store.

You can also be your own CA, which was done often in years past, when you had to pay for a server cert. These days, if you want a free cert, you can just use [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/), or one of several other providers of free certificates.

If you need to validate the client when negotiating the SSL connection, then you would also put a certificate on the client. But, you can't just have the client generate it's own certificate. You'll need to have your CA generate and sign the certificate, and then give that to the client, who would need to add it to their keystore.

Again, in this case, you can act as your own CA, and generate "self-signed" certificates.

If you'd like to see an example of this, I wrote a [blog post](https://chariotsolutions.com/blog/post/https-with-client-certificates-on) for my employer's web site about nine or ten years ago about doing this with an Android app.

Comment: That worked! I created a new keystore with my letsEncrypt certs, which worked without a trust store on the client side. Thank you for the help!

Comment: The client does not need the intermediate certificates in it's trust store and it's usually a bad idea to put them there. The server is supposed to send the intermediate certificates along with it's own certificate.

Comment: @president-james-k-polk
Yes, you are correct. 
It's been a while since I've done this :-)